# On-Off tagging of digital conversations

Tags: audio, media, signal-processing

In a normal conversation between two parties, say A and B, four possible events can happen: 1) Both A and B talk 2) A talks and B is silent 3) A is silent and B talks 4) Both A and B are silent

I would like to create a text file where I report in which state the conversation is, for every time window of some milliseconds.

In particular, I would like to know if there is already a repository for this [based on a number of sample conversations] and, if not, how I can do this, since I do not have much experience in this kind of things (or if I can use an application for it).

Comment: If the only thing you have is a record containing the sum of the signals from A and B, it's pretty hard to do for arbitrary signals. It's much easier if you have the sum and one of the signals as you have in e.g. a phone or modem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we assume that the parties speak at same pitch through out, you could use a pitch determination algorithm to identify the users individual pitch and then compare it at all frames.